# how to calculate remainder of an integer division in jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to make a mod in jinja2 but no way.

{% set index = 1 %}

option 1:

```
{% for .... %}
    {% if {{index % 3 == 0}} %}

    {% endif %}
    {% set index = index  + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

option 2:

```
{% for .... %}
   {% if index.index is divisibleby 3 %}

   {% endif %}
   {% set index = index  + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

You just need to remove the {{ }} from your first if statement.  This code works...

```
<!--    {% set index = 9 %} -->
{% set index = 10 %}
    {% if index % 3 == 0 %}hi
    {% endif %}
{% set index = index  + 1 %}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `batch` filter:

```
{% for item_batched in items|batch(3) %}
   {% for item in items_batched %}

   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#batch