# rendering dictionary in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

with this code I am rendering dictionary from flask backend using jinja template. if dictionary contains 30 items then they will be rendered one by one in a single column.

but
i want to render first 10 items in column 1, next 10 in column 2 and next 10 in column 3
i.e each column should contain at max 10 items

as size of dictionary is not fixed, how can i make sure that i create only required number of columns?

how to modify this code such that maximum 10 items are rendered per column?

```
 <table style="margin-top: 20px;">
        
        {% for key, value in dict.items() %}
        <tr style="margin-bottom: 10px">
            
             <td    {{key}}   </td>
             <td  click  </td>
             <td>  {{value}}  </td>

        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

**update**

```
<table>
    {%- for row in dict|batch(3) %}
    <tr>
        {%- for key in row %}
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        {%- endfor %}
    </tr>
    {%- endfor %}
</table>
```

this is because each row is a list, which contains key of dictionary.
i want to access value also.
how to do it?

**working code**

```
   <table>
        {%- for row in dict.items()|batch(3) %}
        <tr>
            {%- for key,value in row %}
            <td>{{ key }}</td>
            
            <td>{{ value }}</td>

            {%- endfor %}
        </tr>
        {%- endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Do you really mean column? Given you have 1000 items, your users would have to scroll horizontal a lot - which is not really a nice thing to do in web browsers.

Comment: Use the batch filter https://stackoverflow.com/a/41290390/10753968

Comment: @Still_learning  with the link you provided i wrote code, but i am only able to access the keys of dictionary and not value.  can you please show me how to do it?  i have updated the code in question. please look.

Comment: Try `{%- for key, value in row %}`

Comment: row is a list i think

Comment: resolved the issue, thank you @Still_learning, i have updated the working code